# C# VS2010 - Why am I getting the message "An object reference is required for the non-static field"?

Tags: c#

I've boiled this problem down to a very simple program:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    TextBox tb1;

    tb1 = textBox1;             // this line is OK
    tb1 = this.textBox1;        // this line is OK
    tb1 = Form1.textBox1;       // this line generates error message    

    }
```

If you mouse over 'textBox1', 'this.textBox1', and 'Form1.textBox1', the tool tip says "TextBox Form1.textBox1" in all cases.

(see www.firish.com/tb1.jpg and www.firish.com/tb2.jpg for screen dumps showing tool tips)

I passed this around the office a bit but no one here could really explain why the 3rd example doesn't compile but didn't get much other than 'uh-huh', 'hmm...' and a couple of shrugs.

Comment: I would suggest you need to find other developers to work with.

Comment: Is your team made up of primarily VB.NET programmers?

Comment: OK, guys, maybe I deserved that. :)  We basically all brain-farted because the Tool-Tip description derailed us.  But thanks, everyone, who responded so quickly.

Comment: Ah, my comment wasn't meant as a slight against VB.NET programmers—I'm one of them myself. But VB.NET, for the purposes of retaining backwards compatibility with VB 6, implements things a little bit differently, allowing you to write things like `Form1.Show` without first creating an instance of a `Form1` object.

Comment: @user1408942: With those `'uh-huh', 'hmm...' and a couple of shrugs`, i think you should offer some jobs to sharp developers.

Answer (score 6):

Because Form1 is the name of the class, not an instance of Form1.

When you created the class your code looked like this

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
```

here `f` is the instance of the class Form1 and you can use (provided textbox1 is visible)

```
TextBox tb1 = f.TextBox1;
```

Inside the class Form1 you could reference the current instance using the keyword `this`

Answer (score 1):

Because with this syntax you can only access `static` members. `textBox1` is a dynamic member, which can be accessed ONLY from an initialized object. `myObject.textBox1`. You are trying to do `MyClass.textBox1`.

Comment: Thank you, it's very clear now what happened.  And thanks to everyone else (to avoid posting/spamming 1000 thank you notes :)  )

Answer (score 1):

textBox1 is an instance variable.  It must exist in an instantiated copy of the object.  This happens when you say something like this:

```
Form1 form new Form1();
form.textBox1 = "Something";
```

If you do not instantiate the object, it is using a static invocation, and you cannot invoke objects that are instance variables statically.

```
Form1.textBox1 = "Something"; // this fails.
```

In your case, you are using a constructor.  Constructors only get called when an object is instantiated, thus using this (or the the implied this) works, but using the static invocation does not because there is no instance to assign the variable to.