# “An object reference is required for the non-static field” revisited

Tags: c#, oop

[In a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693626/c-sharp-vs2010-why-am-i-getting-the-message-an-object-reference-is-required-f) I asked about the subject title error message, and the answer was almost blindingly obvious.

However, that 'boiled down' example was from some code that was not quite so diluted, and now the original question pops up again in my new broth.

I suspect I may be opening myself up to a lot of 'interesting' comments but hey... there are no such things as stupid questions, only stupid programmers!"

Anyway, here is an only slightly boiled version of the original code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static Form1 mForm = new Form1();


    // define textbox parameter structure
    struct ParmStruct
    {
        public TextBox sTextBoxName;
        public double dMinValue;
        public double dMaxValue;

        public ParmStruct(TextBox sTextBoxName, double dMinValue, double dMaxValue)
        {
            this.sTextBoxName = sTextBoxName;
            this.dMinValue = dMinValue;
            this.dMaxValue = dMaxValue;
        }
    }

    // Create list of Parameters (name, min, max)
    static ParmStruct[] ParmList = new ParmStruct[]
    {
        new ParmStruct { sTextBoxName = mForm.textBox1, dMinValue = -99, dMaxValue = 99 },
        new ParmStruct { sTextBoxName = textBox2, dMinValue = 0, dMaxValue = 100 } 
    };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged); 
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb1;

        tb1 = mForm.textBox1;
        tb1 = textBox2;

        double x = ParmList[0].dMaxValue;
    }
}
```

The second line of the ParmList initialization `(sTextBoxName = textBox2)` will not compile unless I make it `sTextBoxName = mForm.textBox2.`

However, the line `tb1 = textBox2` will compile, and not require the mForm. prefix.

This is the actual case that originally caused the confusion (and still does, as far as I am concerned).

Not really sure why the compiler (VS 2010) can figure it out in one case but not the other.

Oh... and the code does work when compiled. :)

Comment: Can you show where and how the textboxes are both declared?

Comment: @3Pi Probably in the `Form1.Designer.cs`

Comment: Probably, but assumptions in programming are often a source of errors. Better to make certain, especially with 2 objects that should be behaving the same way but aren't

Comment: @3Pi You *have* to make assumptions to answer a question like this one.

Comment: Same answer as previous question...

Comment: `public static Form1 mForm = new Form1();` is your first mistake.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem.

```
// Create list of Parameters (name, min, max)
static ParmStruct[] ParmList = new ParmStruct[]
{
    new ParmStruct { sTextBoxName = mForm.textBox1, dMinValue = -99, dMaxValue = 99 },
    new ParmStruct { sTextBoxName = textBox2, dMinValue = 0, dMaxValue = 100 } 
};
```

It doesn't make any sense for this variable to be shared among all instances of `Form1` (which is what the `static` keyword does), because each instance of the form has its own unique `textBox2`.  Furthermore, simply removing the `static` keyword, as Chris suggested, isn't a fix either.  You can't refer to `textBox2` until it has been created, and that happens inside `InitializeComponent` (called by `Form1` constructor).  This will be better:

```
// list of Parameters (name, min, max)
ParmStruct[] ParmList;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // now the textboxes exist and can be associated with the structure
    ParmList = new ParmStruct[] {
        new ParmStruct { sTextBoxName = textBox1, dMinValue = -99, dMaxValue = 99 },
        new ParmStruct { sTextBoxName = textBox2, dMinValue = 0, dMaxValue = 100 } 
    };

    this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged); 
}
```

Inside both the constructor and `textBox1_TextChanged` method, you can refer to `textBox1` and `textBox2` without any further qualification, the compiler will find the ones belonging to the `this` object, just as if you typed `this.textBox1` (see for example the last like of the constructor).  The compiler will NOT use the textboxes from `mForm`.  In fact, there's no reason for the static `mForm` field, since there's no code to ever display it.

Comment: +1 And the second line does not require an object reference because it's implicitly `this`.

Comment: @Cicada: You mean the `TextChanged` subscription?  That's identical to the code in the question, looks designer-generated.

Comment: OP was wondering why `However, the line tb1 = textBox2 will compile, and not require the mForm. prefix.` I think it's good to explain why it compiles (and does not refer to mForm's field). OP thinks the compiler *figured it out*, but it didn't.

Comment: +1 Yeah, this is the best solution, even if you make the form singleton.

Comment: I like this solution very well (and will probably implement it as such).  But I have to say I have vague misgivings because I am so 'Old School' (40+ years of software, almost all of which did not include objects, events, and classes; hard to teach an old dog new tricks).  The solution above puts the data initialization in the code, and I have all this baggage that insists the data and the code be separate so the example given looks 'odd' to me.  But that is just a perception problem, and I suspect I will get over it. :)  Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 0):

textBox2 is an object that exists only in the context of mForm so you would have to scope it as a field of mForm as it has not been declared in your method or as a [static] object in your class.

Comment: I must say I have never had my questions answered anywhere before in such a timely (and accurate!) manner!

Comment: It does not exist *only* in the context of `mForm`.  Every instance of `Form1` has its own `textBox2`.

Comment: That's true. Yet there is no way for the static constructor of the params to get any instance of textBox2 except the one associated with mForm, so from the perspective of the constructor of the list, it exists only in the context of mForm.